# How or where to obtain the Official Samsung Omnia's SDK

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have searched high and low and cannot find a Samsung Omnia SDK.

I know its possible to use the .net framework for development , but i want more , specifically being able to access the motion sensor and maybe the GPS as well.

Any idea or directions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/category.main.list.do?cateId=147&cateAll=all&platformId=2) you can find SDK and Emulators for Samsung's Omnia, the [second](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/detail.view.do?platformId=2&cateId=147&childCateId=All&childCateId2=&cntsId=1641&imgType=&parentCateId=147&cateAll=all&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fdown%2Fcnts%2Fcategory.main.list.do%3FcateId%3D147%26cateAll%3Dall%26platformId%3D2&previousUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fdown%2Fcnts%2Fcategory.main.list.do%3FcateId%3D147%26cateAll%3Dall%26platformId%3D2) link should lead you to SDK for Samsung's specific API like accelerometer.

GPS should be accessible thru common API [GPS Intermediate Driver Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms850332.aspx) to access it from .NET simple use pinvoke

Comment: Thanks someone else provided me with this same link as well

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the GPS with the GPS intermediate driver. Have a look at the GPS sample from Windows Mobile SDK.

I don't know where to find the Omnia SDK, but if you can't find something in [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/), it would be very hard to locate it.

EDIT: Little bit of search and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=2737837) is a forum post linking to an [SDK](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/10/using-samsung-omnia-accelerometergsenso.html) for the GSensor.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SDK from here: [Omnia WM SDK](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/site/global/docstools/windowsmobile/p_windowsmobile.jsp)